# How to connect two mirth systems through TCP sender and listener

Tags: tcp, hl7, mirth, hl7-v2

I m new to mirth connect and want to know how to connect two mirth machines . im taking data(HL7 message) from database in source on my machine and have to send that data(HL7 message) to another mirth machine on different user .Kindly pray tell the required settings in my mirth destination and another mirth source . i m using windows 7 32 Bit  . and mirth v 3.3.2.7911 .  Also i dont have LLP sender in destination connector .

Answer (score 4):

Mirth supports a variety of connection options. If your machines are on the same network (or VPN), try using the TCP Listener/Sender Connector Type using MLLP. On the receiving side, create a new channel and set up the following settings on the Source tab:

1. Connector Type: TCP Listener
   [image]
2. Listener Settings - Local Address: All interfaces
3. Listener Settings - Local Port: Specify a TCP/IP Port Number (must not conflict with any other ports in use by Mirth or any other software running on this machine)
4. TCP  Listener Settings - Transmission Mode: MLLP
5. Save, enable, and deploy the channel

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirthuserguidev1r7p1/TCP+Listener

On the sending Mirth server, configure the following settings on the destination tab:

1. Connector Type: TCP Sender
2. TCP Sender Settings - Transmission Mode: MLLP
3. TCP Sender Settings - Remote Address: Enter IP Address of the Destination Mirth Server (where you just configured the source channel)
4. TCP Sender Settings - Remote Port: Enter the TCP Port # from the Destination Mirth Server (the port you specified in step 3 of the source channel)
5. Click the 'Test Connection' button next to the IP Address. You should receive a 'Successfully connected to host' message. If you don't, you need to troubleshoot why the machines aren't connecting.)
6. Save, enable, and deploy the channel

On both servers, make sure you save, enable, and deploy the channels. Otherwise, they will not be running and you won't be able to do anything. I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know how it is possible that the user does not have an LLP sender on his MirthBox.